# SQL Importing Large CSV, Out of Memory Error

Tags: sql, memory, csv, import

I am trying to import a large (65mb) CSV file into a SQL table.  I am using phpMyAdming and xampp.  I have changed the following settings in php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 6000M
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

When I try this I get error 'Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1852047360) (tried to allocate 262145 bytes) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\import.lib.php on line 294'

What can I do to solve this error? I would also like to import a much larger database as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could you break the file up into chunks?

Comment: I tried this before I could get the memory_limit raised and it had a similar error.  I've seen people online getting large files to work and since I will soon have to import a much larger csv file I would like to get this working so I can avoid breaking the file into 100 pieces

Comment: I just tried again and it's still running out of memory after I lengthen the max execution time

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Python/PHP/Ruby script to read the file and parse the data, and run INSERT statements row by row.

Comment: I have a Java program that wrote the CSV file.  For some reason, when I try writing to the table from java, the table took about 17 hours to create and for the larger table I want to create would take about a month.  I was hoping this would be much faster.  My current db is 7 columns with one 10-digit int and six 2-digit ints, and 2.5million rows.  I don't know why it is taking so long when I try to write to it from java

Comment: Well you could build a large query instead of writing every time, that was more what I was thinking.

Comment: And the other option is the BULK INSERT

Comment: This doesn't seem to go any faster

Comment: @user1441453 - (Edit) Which method is not faster? Also, it is important to include your database type and version with any sql question. So we know what options are available to you :)