# Java SQL Optimization

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to use an SQL database with a Java program.  I make a table that is 7 columns wide and 2.5 million rows (My next one I need to build will be about 200 million rows). I have two problems: building the SQL table is too slow (about 2,000 rows/minute) and searching the database is too slow (I need to find over 100 million rows in under a second if possible, it currently takes over a minute).  I have tried creating a csv file and importing it, but [I can't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926768/sql-importing-large-csv-out-of-memory-error).

I am using xampp and phpMyAdmin on my computer (i5 + 6gb ram).  I have three methods I am testing: createTable(), writeSQL(), and searchSQL().

createTable:

```
public static void createTable() {
    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "PokerRanks4";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;                                                                        
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ///////////////
    String table = "CREATE TABLE ranks(deckForm bigint(10) NOT NULL,rank0 int(2) NOT NULL,rank1 int(2) NOT NULL,rank2 int(2) NOT NULL,rank3 int(2) NOT NULL,rank4 int(2) NOT NULL,rank5 int(2) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (deckForm),UNIQUE id (deckForm),KEY id_2 (deckForm))";
    try {
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(table);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ///////////////

    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

writeSQL():

```
public static void writeSQL() {
    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "PokerRanks4";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;                                                                        
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /////////////// Prepared Statement with Batch   
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO ranks VALUES (? ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)";      
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                statement.setLong(1, (i*100 + j));
                statement.addBatch();
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            statement.executeBatch();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (statement != null) {
        try {
          statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } // nothing we can do
      }
      if (connection != null) {
        try {
          connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } // nothing we can do
      }       
    }
    System.out.println("Total Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    ///////////////

}
```

searchSQL():

```
public static void searchSQL() {
    String driverName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String serverName = "localhost";
    String mydatabase = "PokerRanks2";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;                                                                        
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    /////////////// Option 1, Prepared Statement
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String query = "SELECT rank0, rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, rank5 FROM ranks WHERE deckForm = ?";
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);             
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {              
            pstmt.setLong(1, 1423354957);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {             
                int[] arr = {rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6)};               
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
    System.out.println("Total Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    ///////////////

    /*
    /////////////// Option 2
    Statement st = null;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    try {
        st = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        long deckForm = 1012213456;             
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {          
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT rank0, rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, rank5 FROM ranks WHERE deckForm = " + deckForm);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int[] arr = {rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6)}; 
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
    System.out.println("Total Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    ///////////////
    */


    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sorry that's so long.  I've tried everything I can think of to make this faster but I can't figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Which version?  Do you have any indices on your tables?  What does the query optimizer tell you about the `select` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a few improvements you could make:

1. You are creating a connection each time you want to search, write or create,
   you should use a pooled connection and datasources.
2. Optimize your queries by doing explain plans, and optimize your table relations and indexes.
3. You can use stored procedures and call them.

Well that's all I can help with, certainly there are more tips.

Answer (score 0):

As to the insert speed, you need to disable all the indexes prior to doing the insert and re-enable them after you're done.  Please see [Speed of Insert Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) for a lot of detailed information on improving bulk insert speed.

The query speed is probably limited by your CPU and disk speeds.  You may have to throw much more hardware at the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the indexes when creating the table and even dropped it from 7 columns to 2 and I'm still getting the same speed (about 2000 rows/min) does that seem right?  I plan on putting this on a server that will be much faster than my pc, but I've heard people say building this table should be much much faster than it is.  Also, fwiw building this data in a csv takes about a minute compared to 17 hours for sql

Comment: That's only 33 rows/second and seems extremely slow unless there's a bottleneck in I/O or the system is otherwise heavily loaded.  You might consider editing your post to include detailed hardware specs (CPU model and speed, bus speed, memory speed and capacity, disk RPM and interface type).

Answer (score 0):

> building the SQL table is too slow (about 2,000 rows/minute)

So point of view on inserting a great number of rows is sure use `Heap table`, it's basic table, also it named as persistent page-array usually created just by `CREATE TABLE`, it's not effective for searching as you meant that search is slow but for inserting is very efficient because it add rows to first free position that what find or on the end of table. But on other hand, searching is very inefficietly, because is not guaranteed sort of items/rows.

> searching the database is too slow (I need to find over 100 million
>   rows in under a second if possible, it currently takes over a minute)

So for this you should create table in that is searching is efficiently. In a case if you using `Oracle`, so it offers many constructions for physical implementation for example `Index organized tables`, `Data clustering`, `Clustered tables` - Index / Hash / Sorted hash ...
`SQL Server` i'm not sure but also clustered tables and `MySQL` i don't know exactly, i don't want to tell you something worst. I don't say that MySQL is bad or worse like Oracle for example but just not offer some techniques for physical implementation like `Oracle` for example

---

So, i mean that it's quite hard to say some recommendations for this approach but you seriously think and study something about physical implementations of database systems, have look at relational algebra for optimize your statements, which types of tables you should create, **@duffymo** meant right that you can let explain your query execution plan by `EXPLAIN PLANE FOR` and based on result to optimize. Also how to use `indexes`, it's strong database construction but each index mean much more operations for any modifying of database so well to rethink for which attribute you create index etc.

Via Google, you find many useful articles about data modeling, physical implementation etc.

Regards man, I wish best of luck